# VBScript - Effecient Close Of Excel Workbook and Application

Tags: excel, vbscript

I am running a VBS macro in our ERP that opens a target Excel Document and populates the form with data from a workbook. The program works but the execution time is roughley 1 and a half minutes.

I placed sMsgBox's at diffrent points in the script to see where the lag was comming from, and the entire script executes in about 4 to 5 seconds, but when watching active processes in Task Manager, I can see that Execl remains open for roughley 1 and a half minutes, and when it does close, the ERP application refreshes and populates with the data.  Script is bellow

```
Dim WshShell 
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")


Dim yr
yr = InputBox("Please enter the payroll year")


Dim wk
wk = InputBox("Please enter the payroll week")


Dim path
path = "K:\Accounting\Payroll\JE\" & yr & "\Hourly\WK " & wk & "\RZU Payroll Template.xlsx"


Function FileExists(FilePath)
     Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
     If fso.FileExists(FilePath) Then
          FileExists=CBool(1)
     Else
          FileExists=Cbool(0)
     End If
End Function


If FileExists(path) Then
     Dim objExcel, objWorkbook, objSheet
     Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
     Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(path)
     Set objSheet = objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(3)


     Dim row
     row = 3


     Do While row <=28 
          val1 = objSheet.Cells(row,2).value
          val2 = objSheet.Cells(row,4).value
          val3 = objSheet.Cells(row,5).value
          WshShell.SendKeys "{INSERT}"
          WshShell.SendKeys val1
          WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
          WshShell.SendKeys val2
          WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
          WshShell.SendKeys val3
          row = row + 1
     Loop


     objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Close
     objExcel.Workbooks.Close
     objExcel.Application.Quit
     Set objExcel = Nothing
Else
     MsgBox("Your entries resulted in an invalid File Path.  Please check the file location and try again")
End If

MsgBox(val1)
```

I believe I using ineficent code to close the Excel file, I would expect the application to close as soon as the command is executed but that does not seem to be the case.

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create multiple objects without disposing of them by setting them to Nothing, like `fso`, `WshShell`, `objWorkbook` and `objSheet`.
This may cause the delay you are experiencing.

Also, the script uses only Global variables (declared outside of a Function or Sub), and these variables do not go out of scope (get "Garbage Collected") until VBScript is reset or destroyed.
For that reason, I have re-written your code so everything Excel is done inside a helper function.

```
Option Explicit

Dim yr, wk, path, lastInsertedValue
yr = InputBox("Please enter the payroll year")
wk = InputBox("Please enter the payroll week")
path = "K:\Accounting\Payroll\JE\" & yr & "\Hourly\WK " & wk & "\RZU Payroll Template.xlsx"

Dim WshShell, fso
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

If fso.FileExists(path) Then
    lastInsertedValue = Do_ExcelStuff(path)
    'you may check this lastInsertedValue if you like:
    'MsgBox(lastInsertedValue)
Else
    MsgBox("Your entries resulted in an invalid File Path.  Please check the file location and try again")
End If

'clean up objects
Set fso = Nothing
Set WshShell = Nothing


Function Do_ExcelStuff(ByVal path)
    'Helper function to do all Excel work using variables local to the function.
    'This means they go out of scope when the function ends and should be freed immediately.
    Dim objExcel, objWorkbook, objSheet, row, val1, val2, val3

    Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False

    Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(path)
    Set objSheet = objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(3)

    row = 3
    Do While row <= 28 
        val1 = objSheet.Cells(row,2).value
        val2 = objSheet.Cells(row,4).value
        val3 = objSheet.Cells(row,5).value
        WshShell.SendKeys "{INSERT}"
        WshShell.SendKeys val1
        WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
        WshShell.SendKeys val2
        WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
        WshShell.SendKeys val3
        row = row + 1
    Loop

    objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Close
    objExcel.Workbooks.Close
    objExcel.Quit
    'clean up objects
    Set objWorkbook = Nothing
    Set objSheet = Nothing
    Set objExcel = Nothing

    'return the last value inserted to prove the code did something
    Do_ExcelStuff = val1
End Function
```

P.S. **A very crude way** of getting rid of the Excel process is to kill it right after the last
`Set WshShell = Nothing` statement.
It may cause data loss and the risk is all yours, but if you want to know how to do that, here's a small helper function for you:

```
Function KillExcel()
   On Error Resume Next

   Dim objWMIService, colProcess
   Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}" & "!\\.\root\cimv2")

   Set colProcess = objWMIService.ExecQuery ("Select * From Win32_Process",,48)
   For Each objProcess in colProcess
      If LCase(objProcess.Name) = "excel.exe" Then
         objWshShell.Run "TASKKILL /F /T /IM " & objProcess.Name, 0, False
         objProcess.Terminate()
      End If
   Next
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks Theo, a lot of good info there, unfortunantly the execution time was still right at 1min 20 sec, even with the kill function.  Could it be the network?  The ERP and the Excel file both live on diffrent drives, both of which are access restricted.  As a programer, Im deffiantly a novice, with networks, Im something less than that

Comment: @Dru I can't see anything that you can do more in VBScript to speed up the process, unless maybe by setting `objExcel.Visible = False` after creating the object. The lag must IMO have some other cause then.Perhaps you can try running this on your local machine using a copy of the Excel file to see the difference in execution speed?

Comment: Thanks again Theo, learned a few things and have some direction now.  Much appreciated